# App\Http\Controllers\admin\GolbalModel in laravel 7

Tags: laravel

i am creating one Golbalmodel and i am calling this into `ProfileController` Constructor

Folder structure for models:

- `App/models/Golbalmodel.php`
- `App/Http/Controllers/admin/ProfileControllers`

Why my `Golbalmodel` is not access in Controller, it gives error as

> Illuminate\Contracts\Container\BindingResolutionException
> Target class [App\Http\Controllers\admin\GolbalModel] does not exist.

Golbalmodel.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use DB;

class GlobalModel extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

}
```

Controller

ProfileController

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers\admin;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Models\GlobalModel;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class ProfileController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct(GlobalModel $model)
    {
        $this->model = $model;
    }
    
    public function index()
    {
        return view('admin.login.profile');
    }
    
    public function getAdminDetails(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $code=$request->id;
        echo $code;
        
    }
    
    
    }
```

Comment: Its located on `App\Models\Golbalmodel.php` or `App\Models\admin\Golbalmodel.php` ?

Comment: @sta App\Models\Golbalmodel.php on this path it located

Comment: Did you moved the `GlobalModel` from the `admin` folder ? If so try running `composer dump-autoload` to refresh the autoloader.

Comment: @rachids no its live on cpanel? how can i do in cpanel?

Comment: Sorry I don't use cPanel. Check if you can log in SSH or run console command in your server.

Answer (score 2):

First, the className and filename need to be the same:

```
WRONG: Golbalmodel.php -> GlobalModel
RIGHT: GlobalModel.php -> GlobalModel
```

Second, the Namespaces need to have the first "letter" in uppercase:

```
WRONG: namespace App\Http\Controllers\admin;
RIGHT: namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin;
```

Pay close attention to case-sensitive when writing the name of Classes and Files. See if with these fixes Laravel can load the Model :)